# Access level to Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::forSubQuery() must be public laravel error?

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, query-builder

I have a simple decent query in my laravel application which is nothing but a left join

```
$spDetails = ServiceProvider::from(‘ipay_app.service_providers as sp’)
            ->leftJoin(‘ipay_app_bbps.biller_category as billerCategory’, ‘billerCategory.api_id’, ‘=’, ‘sp.api_id’)->get();
dd($spDetails);
```

but this query returns me an error which states this

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: 
Access level to Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::forSubQuery() must be public 
(as in class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder) 
in file /var/www/api-test3.instantpay.in/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.php on line 130
```

same query when i am running on my local setup it gives me no error but this is in my testing server and i am having no idea why this error occured

any hints or any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be [PHP Bug #61970](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61970) which was fixed in PHP 7.2. Check that you're using the same PHP version locally as you are on your server.

Comment: okay so according to you there is some php version vs laravel version mismatch??

Comment: Yes, potentially. I don't know what version of Laravel or PHP you're using, but I would check that the environment you're using locally, where you said it's working, is the same as the environment you're using on your server.

Comment: Okay let me check once and thanks to you for providing some hints..